# To close the browser and return to the app

Tags: kotlin, flutter

I want to close the browser once received the auth code and return back to the app.  I think that it is platform specific, I am writing Android part with Kotlin, trying to do this task with intent (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) but there is not much infor around for flutter apps. Any suggestions or sample codes would be helpful! Currently the user needs to click a link on the browser to get it closed and redirected to the app, but I want to remove this click action and close the browser and redirect back to the app automatically.

Comment: Have you considered using the WebView plugin? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin - I recently tried it and aside from some issues with the navigation it is ok, IMHO, for our use case. Just a quick idea that popped up in my head when reading your question... Don't know if this is really helpful, hence this comment... :-)

Comment: From my understanding, WebView is not recommended. Embedded User Agents
The IETF encourages developers to avoid embedded user agents, sometimes referred to as web-views, and use external user-agents, typically the browser. 
Embedded user-agents are unsafe for use by third parties to the authorization server by definition, as the app that hosts the embedded user-agent can access the user’s full authentication credential, not just the OAuth authorization grant that was intended for the app...